# Find files between two specific sizes in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to find files that are bigger than 2 MB for example, and less than 10 MB.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty file managers that can do that, but since you specified cmd.exe, here's a sample DOS batch script. `~z` gives you the filesize of a file.

```dos
set min=2000000
set max=10000000

for /r %%f in (*.*) do (
    if /i %%~zf GEQ %min% (
        if /i %%~zf LEQ %max% (
            echo %%~zf %%f 
        )
    ) 
)
```